# Остановить перехват out и err

Tags: c++

Начинаю перехват потоков out и err в файл, но как остановить перехват после выполнения определенной команды?

```
int file_desc = open(path_out.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
dup2(file_desc,2);
dup2(file_desc,1);
```

Comment: Попробуйте просто закрыть file_desc

Comment: посмотрите сюда

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Типо такого `close(file_desk);` ? Это не помогло. `pclose` и `fclose` то же не помогло.

Comment: Напишите подробнее, что должно происходить по `"остановить перехват"`? (и что вы вообще называете "перехватом"?). / А лучше распишите русскими словами, что именно вы во всей задаче собираетесь  делать

Comment: @avp , Мне надо перехватывать поток вывода и ошибок файл. После чего выполняется некоторый код. После чего мне надо остановить запись в файл и вывести в консоль.

Comment: @Happy_Sweetice, я правильно понял, что вы хотите, чтобы сначала весь вывод в stdout/stderr (дескрипторы 1/2) попадал в `file_desc`, а потом он туда перестал попадать? (для этого просто закройте 1 и 2 `close(1), close(2)`)  (а что потом должно происходить с выводом stdout/stderr?) / Кстати, не забывайте, что по умолчанию вывод stdout буферизуется (вряд ли вы всюду пишете `write(1, ...)`)

Comment: @avp Если сделаю `close(1)` или `close(2)` получаю Runtime Library. Если `close(file_desc)`, то в файл всё равно записывается. Мне просто временно надо их перехватить, чтобы часть информация в файл записалось, а потом вывод продолжился в консоль.

Comment: Как-то не дочитал ваш коммент -- `После чего мне надо остановить запись в файл и вывести в консоль` -- извините. Сейчас попробую написать, как решать

Comment: @ Happy_Sweetice, ссылка почему-то не отправилась, но avp уже написал в ответе ту же идею, что была в ссылке: сохранить исходные потоки перед использованием dup2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, набросал примерчик, когда вывод stdout/stderr сначала переключается на вывод в лог, а потом **восстанавливается** на ранее связанные с этими дескрипторами ресурсы.

Основная идея состоит в том, что перед переключением дескрипторов stdout/stderr с помощью **dup2()** их необходимо сохранить, сделав копию системным вызовом **dup()**.

После окончания "перехвата" восстанавливаем связь дескрипторов 1/2 (stdout/stderr) с первоначальными ресурсами (используем опять же **dup2()**, чтобы сразу закрыть их ссылки на лог), а затем закрываем ранее созданные копии дескрипторов (поскольку ресурс файловых дескрипторов процесса ограничен (хотя, в данном примере это и не важно)).

Надеюсь, комментарии в тексте программы достаточно проясняют суть процесса.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  FILE *log = fopen(av[1], "w");

  puts("Go...");

  fputs("1\n", log); fflush(log);  // первый вывод напрямую в лог 
  perror("Start");   // это пока еще выводится в консоль

  int save1 = dup(1), save2 = dup(2);  //  важно, сохраним исходные stdout-stderr

  int ofd = dup2(fileno(log), 1);   // теперь вывод stdout пойдет в log
  int efd = dup2(fileno(log), 2);   // теперь вывод stderr пойдет в log

  printf("dup2: %d  out: %d\n", ofd, fileno(log));  // вывод stdout в log
  perror("after dups");                             // вывод stderr в log
  fputs("2\n", log); fflush(log);                   // еще один прямой вывод в log

  dup2(save1, 1);  //  восстановим вывод stdout 
  dup2(save2, 2);  //  восстановим вывод stderr
  close(save1), close(save2);

  fputs("3\n", log); fflush(log);  // и еще один последний прямой вывод в log

  errno = 0;
  // здесь вывод ошибок пойдет уже в старый stderr (консоль)
  if (fclose(log))
    perror("fclose err");
  else
    perror("fclose OK");


  // выведем лог на экран (в старый stdout)
  log = fopen(av[1], "r");
  puts("Log:");
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(log)) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
  puts("--- end log ---");

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

По крайней мере с консолью и stderr/stdout перенаправленными в обычные файлы, а также с конвейером ( `... | cat -n` ) работает

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ gcc tdup.c && ./a.out 1t
Go...
Start: Success
fclose OK: Success
Log:
1
dup2: 1  out: 3
after dups: Success
2
3
--- end log ---
End
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ cat 1t
1
dup2: 1  out: 3
after dups: Success
2
3
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```